# Data coming null from Dynamo using Lambda

Tags: lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I am trying to fetch data from DynamoDB using Lambda but somehow the data are coming empty. See below my lambda code.

```
dynamodb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    callback(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                    callback(null, [{Name: +dataField.Name.S, Birthdate: 
+dataField.Birthdate.N, Phone: +dataField.Phone.N, Address: 
+dataField.Address.S, Role: +dataField.Role.S}]);    
                }
            });


OUTPUT:
[
{
"Name" : ,
"Birthdate" : ,
"Phone" : ,
"Address" : ,
"Role" : 
} 
]
```

Comment: can you show your params? Also, can you try this console log console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

Comment: Sure, from where should get the params?

Comment: I meant the params which is an input to the getItem API. dynamodb.getItem(params.. What is the content of params variable? Show the declaration and value assignment.

Comment: My input data model in API Gateway 
      {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "data",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
    "Name": {"type": "string"},
    "Birthdate": {"type": "integer"},
    "Phone": {"type": "integer"},
    "Address": {"type": "string"},
    "Role": {"type": "string"}
    },
    "required": ["Name", "Birthdate", "Phone", "Address", "Role"]
   }

Comment: Where is `dataField` defined? Shouldn't it be `data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your code that it refer first to data from callback and look to data.Item as getItem is returning item in Item (if your params are correct and for sure theres an object relaying to your params):

```
 dynamodb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    callback(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(data);

                    let dataField = data.Item;

                    callback(null, [{Name: +dataField.Name.S, Birthdate: 
+dataField.Birthdate.N, Phone: +dataField.Phone.N, Address: 
+dataField.Address.S, Role: +dataField.Role.S}]);    
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please remove the "+" sign, that you prefixed before each string value.**

**Instead of this:** (Don't do this)

```javascript
callback(null, [{                                                           
    Name: +dataField.Name.S,                                                   
    Birthdate: +dataField.Birthdate.N,                                         
    Phone: +dataField.Phone.N,                                                 
    Address: +dataField.Address.S,                                             
    Role: +dataField.Role.S                                                    
}]);
```

**Do this:**

```javascript
let dataField = data.Item;                                                  
                                                                            
callback(null, [{                                                           
    Name: dataField.Name.S,                                                 
    Birthdate: +dataField.Birthdate.N,                                      
    Phone: +dataField.Phone.N,                                              
    Address: dataField.Address.S,                                           
    Role: dataField.Role.S                                                  
}]);
```

Comment: The "+" sign enforces type conversion to number.
That is why the string values are showing "null"